# What's the black area on RVIZ?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260650/what%27s-the-black-area-on-rviz?/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-04-28

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Black is obstacles, light gray is observed free space, dark gray is unobserved or unknown space.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-04-29**:
But actually,it seems that those items surrounded by light blue shape are obstacles.What's the difference between the two kinds of obstacles?The black ones are unprocessed data from laser_scan?